# Installing jAlbum with Ubuntu Software Installer

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

Recently I have been unable to install new versions of jAlbum (https://jalbum.net/en/software) with Ubuntu's Software installer, although installing with Terminal is possible using
"sudo dpkg -i Downloads/jalbum_30.2-1_amd64.deb"

It seems that other jAlbum users also have the same problem
https://jalbum.net/forum/thread.jspa?messageID=362852&tstart=0#362852

How to install it with the GUI software installer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install software with GUI, you can use GDebi instead of the default Ubuntu software installer.

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

Then, open the .deb file with gdebi.